# How to set custom action on admin form edit top button in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, blocks, adminhtml, forms

I have one my admin grid in that edit time i add button in top action bar now in that on click i need to set custom action of controller

i try this but not working

```
$this->buttonList->add(
            'convert',
            [
                'class' => 'reset',
                'label' => __('Convert B2bCustomer'),
                'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $buttonUrl . '\')'
                
            ],
            11
        );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check added answer and try. It will work

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code in your file and check.

Please change your controller action in function getButtonUrl()

```
$message = __('Are you sure you want to do this?');
$this->buttonList->add(
    'convert',
    array(
        'label' => __('Convert B2bCustomer'),
        'id'    => 'convert',
        'on_click' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getButtonUrl()}')",
        'class' => 'convert primary' 
    ), -100
);

public function getButtonUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('routername/controller/action', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
}
```

**Cheers!**